# Value Scraping Error C#

Tags: c#, html, screen-scraping, getelementbyid, scrape

I am new to coding in C#, and am making a little program to scrape the current Bitcoin value from Mt.Gox.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
namespace BitcoinValueScraper
{
    public partial class GetValue : Form
{
        public GetValue()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetValue_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate("www.mtgox.com");
            wb.Stop();
            wb.Document.GetElementById("lastPrice").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
        }

    }

}
```

This returns with:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in BitcoinValueScraper.exe Additional information: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object."

Help please!

Comment: You are running the compiled program without debugging? Try debugging it so you can see what line the NullReferenceException is being generated from...

Comment: It could be that `wb.Document` is null. It could be that `wb.Document.GetElementById("lastPrice")` is null. It could be that `textBox1` is null.

Comment: just a comment, instead of scraping you might want to use their api (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#public_information). ie:  http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind to the LoadCompleted Event on the webbrowser control. If you dont do this, document on the control will be null. The page might not be downloaded yet.

Example Code:

```
    public WebBrowser webb;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webb = new WebBrowser();
        webb.LoadCompleted += webb_LoadCompleted;
        webb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    }

    void webb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //NOW DOCUMENT SHOULD NOT BE NULL
        MessageBox.Show("Completed loading the page");

        mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = webb.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
        mshtml.HTMLInputElement obj = doc.getElementById("gs_taif0") as mshtml.HTMLInputElement;
        mshtml.HTMLFormElement form = doc.forms.item(Type.Missing, 0) as mshtml.HTMLFormElement;
    }
```

Above is for windows presentation foundation webbrowser control. In windows forms i believe the event is: DocumentCompleted reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is windows forms code (i just tested this):

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetValue_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void GetValue_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
        wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }

    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Document loading completed");
        //GET YOUR DOCUMENT HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to the code problem you're currently encountering I'd like to highly suggest that you try doing things a different way because trying to pull information out of HTML on a website like that is extremely fragile (if they change their markup at all your code is broken) and just wrong on a lot of levels. In general, programmers usually rely on data APIs for querying this kind of information as it provides a standardized and (hopefully) tested way of querying for information. A quick Google search turned up some Bitcoin API's offered by BlockChain who seem to be pretty well regarded in the bitcoin world. Here is a sample API call to query for Bitcoin exchanges rates:

http://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api

By making an HTTP request to their API you can much more reliably pull down the information that you're looking for and display it in your user interface.

Further Bitcoin API resources can be found here:

http://blockchain.info/api

Unfortunately, as you are new to both programming and interacting with APIs its hard to give you an answer without taking the time to physically write the code for you. However, I can say that currently, your approach is wrong. A WebBrowser object is not a suitable mechanism with which to interact with a web API. A more suitable approach would be to make an HTTP call to the API URL that you posted and then read the JSON out of the response. This would then need to be parsed into some kind of format that makes sense for your application (such as a simple Price object etc). There are many articles online regarding parsing JSON with C# as well as interacting with web based APIs through the HTTP protocol. I'd definitely recommend that you start there.

Here is a great starting article that will walk you through creating a basic application for interacting with JSON APIs. Just replace the Bing URLs with the appropriate BitCoin ones and you should have a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If anything try:

```
    namespace BitcoinValueScraper
    {
        public partial class GetValue : Form
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            public GetValue()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void GetValue_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wb.Navigate("www.mtgox.com");
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_LoadCompleted;
    }
    void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = wb.Document;
        textBox1.Text = doc.GetElementById("lastPrice").ToString();
    }        
         }
```

Comment: while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            wb.Document.GetElementById("lastPrice").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);

Comment: But I still get:

"Debugger:Exception Intercepted: GetValue_Load, Form1.cs line 28
An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occurred.  "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options."

Comment: user2453734 explains why it is null you have to wait for the page to download before you can query the html. Just swap out his GetElementById with lastPrice.